# Async method not working

Tags: c#, wpf, task

When I try to do this:

```
progress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // it just a UI element
var t = Task.Run(() => this.CompareAll()); // CompareAll() is a time consuming operation
t.ContinueWith((result)=> { progress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;  });
```

I get the following error:

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it".

I think I have to use something related to `Dispatcher` but I'm not sure how. I'm using WPF. Any ideas?

Comment: You are attempting to update the GUI from another thread. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625208/accessing-ui-main-thread-safely-in-wpf) has solutions to this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot I read the article and I solved it.