# System.InvalidOperationException when accesing wpf element in Lambda Function

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, lambda

when I execute the following code in my wpf application. I get a `System.InvalidOperationException`, as soon as the code trys to access  `textBoxResult.Text`. I assume it has something to do with scope. I am not that expierenced with c#. Could someone please explain what is the problem and how to do it right?

**Code:**

```
private void buttonRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((timer_e) =>
            {
                textBoxResult.Text = "";
                device.Service.Inputs = textBoxRun.Text;
                device.Service.Run(device.ResourceStore.Resources);
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

        }
```

Comment: Please provide more details on the exception (at least the message). But if it is something like "_The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it_", see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it).

Comment: @Grx70 Thank you,  your link answers my question. Sorry for not providing the message. I did not see it. Otherwise I would have googled the message text.

Comment: Better use a DispatcherTimer. It already runs in the UI thread. Also make sure you don't start a new timer on each Click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know so far, you can only access visual elements from UI thread.

Your lambda is running on different thread. You can use the dispatcher, see this answer :)

[Accessing UI (Main) Thread safely in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625208/accessing-ui-main-thread-safely-in-wpf)

`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* Your code here */ }));`

So, in your case something like:

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((timer_e) =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        textBoxResult.Text = "";
        device.Service.Inputs = textBoxRun.Text;
        device.Service.Run(device.ResourceStore.Resources);
    }
}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Comment: You would certainly move `device.Service.Run(...)` out of the DispatcherAction.

Comment: Most probably yes, I just do not know what it does, so I copied his code. It's up to him now :)