# WPF C# how to call/execute 1 to 4 methods at the same time in the same thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of 1 to 4 mediaplayer objects depending on how may are required at the time by the user
I need to call the Play method on each 1-4 at the same time.

I don't need them to run at the same time in parallel I just need to call the play method so all in the list start at the same time.

At the moment im doing this

```
    foreach(MyMediaPlayer player in lsPlayers)
     {
       player.Play();
     }
```

which works ok but I want to know if there is a better way.

I have tried

```
Parallel.ForEach(ObjectList, (obj) =>
   {
   // Do parallel work here on each object
    });
```

and Parallel.BeginInvoke

but these all seem to launch in a new thread and that causes an error of trying to access controls on different threads.

I just want to initiate the Play() method at the same time for a possible 1 to 4 media player objects

Comment: It isn't possible to call multiple methods at the same time on objects that must be accessed by the UI thread

Comment: using your approch you can use a dispatcher to avoid the error with accessing the controls

Comment: @Denis Schaf 3 Tried that just could not get it working, the same thread error kept coming up

Comment: can you paste the error here?

Comment: by the way even if you get it to work the UI runs on a single thread so even a dispatcher from 4 parallel threads will have to wait for its turn to access the UI
So this only makes sense if your player "wastes" time with non UI related tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't run 4 things at the same time in the Main Thread. Imagine it as a stack where each row is processed once a time, in that case each row is a function.

For what you are doing it should be okay to call all four play methods in series, in the Main Thread, since you shouldn't perceive any delay in all 4 players. Threading works better when you have compute-intensive tasks that would block the interface. For that you should refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11625264/11042363