# Cannot access BitmapImage from async Task

Tags: c#, wpf, task, dispatcher, bitmapimage

I have code which generates an image doing lots of things, so I run it as `async Task`. After the generation is completed the image should be displayed in the `Image` WPF element. But I get `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'`

```
BitmapImage? img = await Task.Run(GenerateResultPhoto);
PhotoResult.Source = img; //Exception here
 
private BitmapImage? GenerateResultPhoto()
{
    //Lots of things going there in actual code
    //But any returned BitmapImage is inaccessible
    return new BitmapImage();
}
```

Using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` changes nothing:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    PhotoResult.Source = img; //Same exception
}));
```

Comment: So marshal your code/data to the UI thread and run it there?

Comment: @UweKeim What's the best way to do this? I'm not skilled in C# async, so even my Task approach may be wrong.

Comment: I do think [this is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11625264/107625).

Comment: My bad, this actually is a direct duplicate and the cited question has the right answer - you need to Freeze the BitmapSource before returning it outside the worker thread.

Comment: @EmperorEto that's what I did and it worked.